# Get specific files (Google Sheet) from sub-folders (on Google Drive) and then change a value of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to change a value of a Google sheet cell in multiple google sheets using Google Script.

I have a Folder that has 80 subfolders one for each agent. Within each subfolder I have a Google Sheet with a title of "Time Management Agent View - nameOfAgent". I want to set the value of Cell B4 in each sheet [1] to a new value.

I have tried this and it does not work. When I try to log the agentSheet, It comes out blankAs is probably evident from the code i am very new and untrained in this ;) Thank you for your help.

Filip

```
var regex = "'Time Management Agent View' + /.*/"
var agentsFolderId = 'Folder_ID';

  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(agentsFolderId).getFolders();

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var agentFolder = folders.next();
    var allAgentsSheets = agentFolder.getFilesByName(regex);
    Logger.log(agentFolder);
    Logger.log(allAgentsSheets);

    while (allAgentsSheets.hasNext()){
      var agentSheet = allAgentsSheets.next();
      Logger.log(agentSheet);
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(agentSheet);
      var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activeSpreadsheet.getSheets()[1]);
      var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(activeSheet.getRange(2, 4))
      var cellToChange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()

      cellToChange.setValue('Test')

    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out!

```
var str = 'Time Management Agent View'
var regex = /.*/
var agentsFolderId = 'Folder_ID';

  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(agentsFolderId).getFolders();

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var agentFolder = folders.next();
    var allAgentsSheets = agentFolder.searchFiles('title contains "Time Management Agent View"');
    Logger.log(agentFolder);
    Logger.log(allAgentsSheets);

    while (allAgentsSheets.hasNext()){
      var agentSheet = allAgentsSheets.next().getId();
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.openById(agentSheet));

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
      var cell = sheet.getRange("B4");
      cell.setFormula('New_Formula');
      var cellContent = cell.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply this area:

```
while (allAgentsSheets.hasNext()){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(allAgentsSheets.next().getId());
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
```

You don't need to use setActive and getActive.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have implemented your suggestions and am starting to understand it all a bit better.